# Custom CDI Extension not always detected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, cdi, weld

In my project, my WAR has a dependency on a custom submodule which contains a custom CDI extension. The extension must prepare specific beans for injection. It works fine... except when it does not. Sometimes the extension is loaded and beans injected, sometime the extension is not (extension not even instancied and intellij put the breakpoints in grey).

I can guess it has to do with the deployment/server startup but I have no idea where to look.

Configuration :

- Java (JEE) 1.8
- Wildfly 9.0.2
- Weld 2.2.16
- CDI 1.2 (because Wildfly 9)
- Intellij 2017.2.6

I'm obviously not asking for a ready to use solution, but for input for where I should start looking at.

**EDIT :** The META-INF directory of the submodule itself has a beans.xml and declares the extension in services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension according to the documentation.

Comment: You need to describe the deployment a bit. Is it a WAR with a dependency/lib where the extension is? Or is it WFLY module? Also make sure you have beans.xml in the archive with extension and that the extension is enabled in META-INF.

Comment: I have expanded my question to answer you.

Comment: `In my project, my WAR has a dependency on a custom submodule` - are you talking about WildFly module here? Or just plain old library inside WAR?